# Swagger : Get method using body is not working also changed into the query, path, header still not working

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-editor

i am making openapi.yaml till now as well as deploying my test API's on the google cloud endpoints is working but now i made some changes i am sending parameter in body to the get api (e.g email) and getting some response but actually on the local it is working fine with postman after deploying openapi.yaml file it is not working on the google cloud endponits portal

So, anybody has any solution or answers for this so please help me

For safety i am also sharing error screenshot also y code snippet

```
"/api/getRecords":
   get:
    description: "Get All Records Details."
    operationId: "getRecords"
    produces:
      - "application/json"    
    parameters:
    - description: "Message to getRecords"
      in: query
      name: getRecords
      type: object
      required: false
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"         
    responses:
      200:
```

Also,

[image]

Comment: In OpenAPI 2.0, query parameters cannot be objects, they can only be primitive values or arrays of primitives. Is the `echoMessage` object supposed to be sent in the request body? If so, change the HTTP method to `post`, change the parameter type to `in: body` and remove the `type`.

Comment: if i changed into string then still not working (type : string)

Also, i can not make changed every Http Post Method instead of Get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your code like this :

```
# [START swagger]
  swagger: "2.0"
  info:
    description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
    title: "Endpoints Example"
    version: "1.0.0"
  host: "abc.appspot.com"
# [END swagger]
  parameters:
    email:
      name: email
      in: query
      type: string
      required: true
```

Then use shorthand syntax in the path:

```
path:
 "/api/getRecords":
   get:
     description: "Get All Records Details."
     operationId: "getRecords"
     parameters:
       - $ref: "#/parameters/email"
     responses:
       200:
         description: "Get records details"
         schema:
           $ref: "#/definitions/postMessage"
```

It will work.